# fontAwesome and Apple Keynote 6.5

Tags: font-awesome, osx-yosemite, keynote

After upgrading to Yosemite (10.10) and Keynote 6.5, fontAwesome is working while I'm designig my presentation, but it fails when I export to PDF.

The icons are smaller and bad positioned in the exported version.

Can you understand why?

Comment: I'm actually experiencing this same issue and I've tried using the latest font awesome build 4.2.0

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue: Uninstalling the .otf version of the font and installing the .ttf one fixed the issue.